# VSCode PowerShell terminal running commands one line at a time instead of all at once

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am at a loss as to why my terminal in VSCode while using PowerShell has stopped running commands like it use to.  I highlight a few commands in the editor and then press F8.  I believe the issue has something to do with VSCode Terminal.  Integrated vs External.

What I expect:

1. Highlight code and press F8 key
2. Terminal displays and runs all code that was highlighted
3. Terminal displays all output of the commands run

What I am now getting:

1. Highlight code and press F8 key
2. Terminal displays and runs first line of code
3. If there is any output, the terminal displays it
4. Terminal displays and runs next line of code
5. If there is any output, the terminal displays it
6. Repeat steps 4-5 until all code has run

Test Code that is highlighted and run using F8:

```
$a = 5
Write-Host $a
$b = $a + 5
$c = $b + 5
Write-Host $c
```

What my terminal shows now:

```
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> $a = 5     
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> Write-Host $a
5
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> $b = $a + 5
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> $c = $b + 5
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> Write-Host $c
15
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack>
```

What the terminal use to/should show:

```
PS C:\_MyPSModules\hab_hpe_win_driverpack> $a = 5
Write-Host $a
$b = $a + 5
$c = $b + 5
Write-Host $c
5
15
```

Comment: Powershell has different output types (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3)  What may of happened is your powershell configuration changes and output are now handled different.

Comment: It might be what operation control v is bound to.

Comment: @jdweng, the question is about ultimately receiving _the same output_, but with the input unexpectedly being _submitted differently_ than before and the output _sequencing_ being different.
As such, it is unclear how your comment about output _types_ is relevant. The rest of your comment about a "configuration change" and "output [...] now handled differently"
provides no useful information beyond the premise of the question: _something changed_.

Comment: @js2010, the question is about pressing F8.

Comment: @mklement0 : We do not know the types of outputs that is being shown.  All we know is the output is different and do not know the reason for the change.  The powershell configurate files could of changed and now we are not seeing all of the outputs, or previously we were seeing all the outputs and not we are only seeing some of the outputs.

Comment: @mklement0 it's a pretty wild guess, but the behavior sounds like what happens when the control v (paste) binding changes.

Comment: @js2010, I can see the parallel, but I don't think there's any pasting involved at all when the PowerShell extension submits code to the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console), which leads me to believe that (a) either the PIC isn't the active shell in the integrated terminal or (b) a _different_ extension (or key binding) is handling F8.

Answer (score 0):

Your symptom implies one of two things:

- **Either**: The PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) that comes with Visual Studio Code's **[PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)** - which is a special-purpose edition of PowerShell that facilitates editing and debugging of PowerShell code - is *not the active shell* in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal at the time you're pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>

  - If it *is* the active shell (see below for how to verify), the selection *as a whole* is submitted to the PowerShell instance running in the PIC, which is what you expect.
  - Otherwise, the selection is submitted *line by line* to *whatever shell happens to be running* in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.

    - If that shell happens to be PowerShell too (running as a *general-purpose* shell), the submitted code *may or may not* work, depending on what the selection contains.
- **Or**: A different Visual Studio Code extension has remapped the <kbd>F8</kbd> key to submit the active editor's selection *line by line* to the active shell.

  - To see if it is the still the PowerShell extension's <kbd>F8</kbd> key mapping is in effect, execute "PowerShell: Run Selection" from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd>) and see it shows "F8" to the right.
  - Conversely, to see what <kbd>F8</kbd> is currently bound to, execute 
    "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>), click on the [image: keyboard icon] icon to the right of the search field and press <kbd>F8</kbd>, and see what command(s) show up with the word "editorTextFocus" in the "When" column.
  - If a different extension has indeed remapped <kbd>F8</kbd>, either uninstall that extension or remap the key as desired.

---

How to **determine if the PIC is the active shell**:

- **Programmatically**:

  - Run `Get-Module PowerShellEditorServices.Commands` in the integrated terminal:

    - (Non-error) output `PowerShellEditorServices.Commands` implies that the PIC is running.
- **Visually**, looking at the top-right corner / the rightmost panel of the integrated terminal:

  - Look for the "PowerShell Extension" shell:

    - If only *one* shell is running, look for this:

      - [image: screenshot one shell]
    - If *multiple* shells are running, look for this entry in the stack of running shells and see if it is the *selected* (active) one; e.g.:

      - [image: screenshot multiple shells]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will be fixed in vscode v1.75, see [Release Notes: bracket paste mode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#bracketed-paste-mode-used-in-run-selected-text-in-active-terminal):

> #### Bracketed paste mode used in "Run Selected Text In Active Terminal"
>
> The `Run Selected Text In Active Terminal` command will now run the
> text using "bracketed paste mode" in supporting shells, so a
> multi-line selection will be treated as a single input, rather than
> multiple commands. This makes running actual scripts much more
> intuitive with less errors occuring.

The commands in a multiline selection will be run as a group rather than individual commands.